# How to triangulate torus(bagel/donut)?

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, triangulation

There are two sets of vertices (Cn and Pn form a polygon with a hole), the vertices are listed sequentially. The number of vertices is Cn = Pn / 2. What is the correct way to triangulate such a polygon? [image]

Comment: If Cn and Pn form a *polygon* with a hole, then what you have there is an [annulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annulus_(mathematics)), not a torus.

Comment: If there are twice as many P vertices than C vertices, you should probably use a different letter for each instead of *n*. Also, just draw it on paper and see what you need to do.

Comment: Every C is facing some P (take the closest). Then join C to P and the predecessor and successor of P. Every P is linked to 3 P's and P's are linked to 1 or 2 C's alternatively.

Comment: Are the polygons always convex?